# Computing Bounding Box After Moving Vertices in Shader

Tags: three.js, shader, bounding-box

In ThreeJS, how can I update the bounding box/sphere after changing vertex positions in a shader?

Edit:
I should've clarified I'm using a particle buffer geometry and changing the vertex positions in the shader. I'm not calling geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are updating vertices in the shader, it is typical to do this, instead:

```
object.frustumCulled = false;
```

three.js r.98

Comment: Yea, I forgot about that.  Thank you, West.

Answer (score -1):

geometry.computeBoundingBox() and geometry.computeBoundingSphere()

Comment: That doesn't work.  I should've clarified I'm using a particle buffer geometry and changing the vertex positions in the shader.  I'm not calling geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

Comment: Oh. then there is no way for three to know the bounding box.. so you'll just have to set it to something yourself that best approximates where your particles might be.